# How works regex in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have collection like:

```
{
"city" : "ACMARE",
"state" : "AL",
"_id" : "001"
}
```

How aggregate this collection by City using regexp? For example: cities which name starts with letter from `D` to `H`? I read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/), but it is still not clear how use regexp.

Comment: do you want to find or do you want to aggregate so that you can sum them or average something or ... something else?  If you provide more specifics, there's higher change that the answer will have enough detail to be more useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this perhaps:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $match: { city : /^[D-H].*/ } }  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Collection.find( { city: /^[D-H]/ } )
```